# how I can sort filenames based on numbers

Tags: shell, sorting, scripting

I have a directory with file in them that have numbers. Ususally the number are the deciding factors in the sort.

however - the file are like

```
f01
f2
f03
f004
f05
f10
```

how can I sort the file based on absolute numeric values if. I understand the alphabet will rearrange the sort - but today a standard sort put 10 ahead of 2

thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ls -v
```

for natural sorting

```
$> ls -v
f01  f2  f03  f004  f05  f10
```

Comment: Yes, this also worked for me: `ls | sort -V` (capital V used here)